# Distribution of Mobius function

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

Let $\mu(n)$ be the Mobius function. 
Let us define $\mu^+(n)$ to be $\mu(n)$ if $\mu(n)>0$ and $0$ otherwise. Is there a known asymptotic formula for 
$$
\sum_{n \leq N} \mu^+(n),
$$ 
and similarly for 
$$
\sum_{ \substack{n \leq N \\ n \equiv a (\mod q)}} \mu^+(n). 
$$
I would greatly any appreciate references or comments. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: I think the results you seek probably follow easily from the identity $\mu^{+}(n) = \frac{\mu(n)^{2} + \mu(n)}{2}$ combined with known results about $\sum_{n \equiv a \pmod{q}, n \leq x} \mu(n)$, and the count of the number of squarefree integers in arithmetic progressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll have a stab at this. The relation 
$$
\sum_{n\leq X:n\equiv a~(mod~q)} \mu^2(n)=\frac{6}{\pi^2} \prod_{p|q}
\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2} \right)\frac{X}{q}+E(X,q,a)
$$
where the error term $E$ is $O_{\varepsilon}\left(\sqrt{X/q}
+q^{\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon}\right) $ provided $q\leq X^{\frac{2}{3}-\varepsilon},$
together with some recent results (assuming GRH) of the form

$$
\sum_{n\leq X:n\equiv a~(mod~q)} \mu(n) \ll_{\varepsilon}
\sqrt{X} \exp\left( (\log X)^{3/5} (\log \log X)^{(16/5)+\varepsilon} \right)
$$

(see the paper on arxiv [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.7326.pdf)) and the observation $\mu^{+} (n)=\frac{1}{2}(\mu(n)+\mu^2(n))$ suffices to yield an answer.

**Edit** The paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.06758.pdf) gives the bound 
$$
O\left( \frac{X}{q\log^C X}\right)
$$

for any $C>0$, for $X$ large enough.

Comment: Is it possible to give me references where RH/GRH is not assumed? Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you possibly provide me the reference for the first estimate also? Thank you very much!